# How to call the same angular component multiple times using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

So I have a component called `custom-modal.component`. The HTML file looks like this:

```
<dialog id="custom-modal">
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</dialog>
```

In the `.ts` file I have

```
this.modal = document.querySelector('#modal-custom');

// Buttons listeners to showModal() and close() methods...
```

The problem comes if I try to call modal multiple times:

```
<button class="open-modal">See cards</button>
<button class="open-modal">See flowers</button>

<app-custom-modal>
  <app-cards></app-cards>
</app-custom-modal>

<app-custom-modal>
  <app-flowers></app-flowers>
</app-custom-modal>
```

So in Angular, this will end up doing:

```
<button class="open-modal">See cards</button>
<button class="open-modal">See flowers</button>

*** NOTE that there's two ***

<dialog id="custom-modal">
 <div> <h1> Cards title </h1> </div>
</dialog>

<dialog id="custom-modal">
 <div> <h1> Flowers title </h1> </div>
</dialog>
```

The querySelector is not going to work as it only selects the first one. I can do a querySelectorAll and loop through every modal but then I don't have a way to assign the button listener to display the correct modal (Or I don't know how to do that).

I don't know if there's a better way to solve this, I just want to make it full re-usable. Sorry for noob questions as I'm Junior developer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't use ngIf on app-custom-modal?

Comment: Uhmm.. but based on what? Because I actually want those 2 modals to be on the page, right now If I click on one button, it will "try" to open those 2 modals at the same time

Comment: create two flags like openFlowers modal and openCardsModal, and set their value true if you want to open both modal, false for one which you want to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important part of this is keeping in mind where you want to handle the open/close state of your dialog.

In this case you are doing it in the component that hosts the modal. What you could do is pass an Input, let's say visible, to the modal that indicates the open/closed state. You can also define an Output that notifies you if the modal was commanded to close from within the modal component.

I also recommend that you should use ViewChild in the modal component instead of document.querySelector(...). Note that with the use of ViewChild you will most likely have to use the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook.

.ts file of the CustomModalComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
// ... the rest of import

@Component({
  // ... Component decorator props (selector, templateUrl, styleUrls)
})
export class CustomModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('modalRef') modalRef: ElementRef;
  @Input() visible: boolean;
  
  // Optional if you want to close the dialog from here and notify the parent (host)
  @Output() closed = new EventEmitter(); 

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // Print the HTMLElement of the modal
    console.log(this.modalRef.nativeElement);

    // Do your thing
  }

  close() {
    this.closed.emit();
    // ...
  }

  // ... the rest of the component
}
```

.html of CustomModalComponent

```
<dialog #modalRef>
 <ng-content></ng-content>
</dialog>
```

Then when you want to use it in the ParentComponent

In your .html

```
<button class="open-modal" (click)="openCards()">See cards</button>
<button class="open-modal" (click)="openFlowers()">See flowers</button>

<app-custom-modal [visible]="visibleCards" (closed)="closeCards()">
  <app-cards></app-cards>
</app-custom-modal>

<app-custom-modal [visible]="visibleFlowers" (closed)="closeFlowers()">
  <app-flowers></app-flowers>
</app-custom-modal>
```

In your .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// ... the rest of import

@Component({
  // ... Component decorator props (selector, templateUrl, styleUrls)
})
export class ParentComponent {
  visibleCards: boolean;
  visibleFlowers: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  openCards() {
    this.visibleCards = true;
    // ...
  }

  openFlowers() {
    this.visibleFlowers = true;
    // ...
  }

  closeCards() {
    this.visibleCards = false;
    // ...
  }

  closeFlowers() {
    this.visibleFlowers = false;
    // ...
  }

  // ... the rest of the component
}
```

Comment: Yeah, actually something similar to this I ended up implementing, thanks for your reponse.